# Function returns none instead of the sum of list

Tags: python

Why does this code return none in Python 2? However if I replace return statement with print statement i.e print sum in the function itself, it gives the right answer. Why is that so? I know it is a silly question but i cant figure it out on my own.

```
import math
n=int(raw_input().strip())
temp = [5]
arr=[]
def cal(arr):
    arr.append(int(math.floor(temp[-1]/2)))
    temp.append(arr[-1]*3)
    if len(arr)==n:
        return sum(arr)
    cal(arr)
print cal(arr)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to

```
return cal(arr)
```

otherwise the function will just call itself recursively and return `None` by default (instead of the calculated result).

Answer (score 2):

The end of the function should read

```
if len(arr)==n:
    return sum(arr)
else:    
    return cal(arr)
```

shouldn't it?  You get `None` as a return value if your function ends without returning a value.